# Frenkel or Tulczyjew-Dixon Condition and QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, quantum-electrodynamics, spinors, degrees-of-freedom

What is the physical motivation behind imposing Frenkel's condition,
$$p_{\mu}S^{\mu\nu}=0$$
for an electron of momentum $p$ and spin given by some tensor $S^{\mu\nu}$?

In addition, a direct implication of imposing the Frenkel condition is that the $S^{0i} (i=1,2,3)$ elements of the spin operator need to vanish in order for the Frenkel condition to be satisfied. But in QED the spin operator is already defined as $S^{\mu\nu}=\frac{i}{4}[\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}]$, and this contradicts with the Frenkel condition (i.e. with $S^{0i}$ being zero). How does one reconciles the definition of the Spin operator in QED with the Frenkel condition? I can come up with 3 different possible explanations...

1. Is the Frenkel condition not applicable in QED, or
2. is there some sort of relaxation in the definition of the Spin operator in QED, such that it is consistent with the Frenkel condition, or
3. is the demand $S^{0i}=0$ too strong of a restriction, and instead we impose $S^{0i}u(p)=0$, with $u(p)$ being the spinor corresponding to the "Frenkel" electron?

**Bonus Question:** What happens in the high energy limit of an electron, in which it can be approximated by a massless fermion of charge $-e$?

**EDIT:** People has been asking whether or not the condition I refer to should be called Frenkel's condition. I have found the name in these papers:

1. [The Covariant Definition of Spin in Relativistic QFT](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272698/1-s2.0-S0031891400X01991/1-s2.0-0031891465901412/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEJT%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCICFcdiL8elScrMKoj7TTd%2B0Y7IBGsLretFM9BEBZ%2FjJKAiEAn4yjdMhaQCZG4CtpGq4eAhbuycar%2F7xhiHSdubteYQ8qswUIbBAFGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDOTlfWvsRlnmHKZSAiqQBbArE7%2B84820nXuxWutosqcY50hZ9zEG8ld7Y1CXjQewue7rxGnA196EBBZ2DK866D9YkjldHYMrABMlkbgV4f7t0Bhi6AFQI6y3%2By9UxBwTDpfG25XuXxbaJRg7TVqckJpc8TAr0Hnitb7%2FRvStR65eSeY4Q1EntK6n0%2FEXeLc9898rVeJWcyLlSN1yCQ%2Brp%2BT%2BzY5ykqP9n5OYxxWkELx7E3sK7VrRLoSOApCMGbZrHzrgKJ9P4kY7yiFyaS91oUIlopRePUFb%2BY9HIiLsUROgP9MAER%2FF2%2F2p%2BrHm6b3m1tVb3kYyJTyaKH5HZ%2BqMdc0mqS7Cih48INQS%2BLCpCdMmEgFIQP0b7jn7Wn64IEV2yGXtpT2BPDyWIRoMXE%2FMaW%2Fm9ELLjOJakxP6Z%2FS1c%2BRxulz73IFhwFxWF9wTm22AIaVHHuJrnrvCcn9%2FJwhYmGLNYeG2sOfylpvz8qjltkFwxg1q181u%2FUv4sbH3KHNPjH9cwE%2FKk%2F%2FNXk5BRkGf7IjQ0B50OnEr6X8rYzNjlDagFXedmwrUtGDFOkHd3QB5enF4efOX2ROphcMAA9k21h1OazWcD6WEeVo6wzVvlayJOeXGXh1Imu4kB8rmnAfBX50kIH6zNemJL13hC6G75lmAUFTAHFlvHblLF1uyA9GAaNyxAop1fkeo%2BaErAnM002C0TQ6Gu6GTAy7%2BN69p93u%2BVxSxFxCc66PVnWRwamyRs9w9f%2BJ2Vn5KPymahxIa4es346b4EYv7oJ3BmN8kqdRkPStAV0aDy7%2Fro2sa1EnrIOSI2uzi6bhQONcIqfzojyOKHR1A8mPGVZwN2j32nvuZYbtXFrNUvnGfF%2ByW0SJct%2F70on8wRhGCYm9KXI5OMM7e36cGOrEB61l5v%2FVMLm3EFbKbpfs2ef0xWpGm%2FPXzt5FKAU8EEHTD3zlevN7dQi54FepCiYuAWpwGjCHogL3s%2FdhOARGO64HFt43x3A2%2FBfu5kULfTSwlvdWtjbxFrPtqhSOcJTutskILPB2yTtKJh3eAXoHWDYTGwQ%2Bdyl0QJrJox%2Bwo5von9%2FIKkn%2B%2Fx5c0SJ93ePvzoLHGfUgEWOJSXnkZHnKclZlHKkjNSFnb2jQBfmLi5zeD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230906T035420Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYVRBTMN4X%2F20230906%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=f26d336355a7813f43fc796de7f685e3be0d7d1b6ab895cf0f137ed2288f5495&hash=ae091e5b30ebfe0ca3a7de72c00057eb711b3daa94ea2d89aa4199d1418baf38&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0031891465901412&tid=spdf-93b55b0b-4af0-4d59-b1b0-37095f6aeca0&sid=b3fd818c6faa15496c6bc3e3b3d0495eb9b6gxrqb&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=061f5d5f565102505351&rr=8023c523ac1673bf&cc=cy),
2. [On the dynamics of classical particle with spin](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.4337.pdf) and
3. [Frenkel electron and a spinning body in a curved
   background](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.5743.pdf)

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/358278/

Comment: Related only with half of my question @JánLalinský. I have seen that before asking, but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

I do not recall   $p_\mu S^{\mu\nu}=0 $ (I assume that you meant ot include the $=0$?) being called the "Frenkel condition". I know it as   the Tulczyjew-Dixon condition [W. M. Tulczyjew, Motion of multipole particles in general relativity theory, Acta Phys. Pol.
18 393-409 (1959);W. G. Dixon, Dynamics of extended bodies in general relativity I. Momentum and Angular
Momentum, Proc. Roy. Soc. A 314 499-527 (1970)]

It is to be constrasted  with  the Mathisson-Pirani condition $u_\mu S^{\mu\nu}=0$ where $u_\mu$ is the four veclocity [M. Mathisson, *Nowa mechanika system ́ow materialnych, Acta Phys. Pol. 6 163 (1937); English Translation: *New mechanics of material systems*, Gen. Rel. Grav. 42 1011-1048 (2010); A. E. Pirani, *On the physical significance of the Riemann tensor*, Acta Phys. Pol. 15
389-405 (1956); Reprinted in Gen. Rel. Grav. 42 1215-1232 (2009)]. Some of the physical significance in connecetion with the Dirac equation is discussed in appendix D of our  arXiv:1406.0354.

PS I just looked up Frenkel and it seems he was ahead of the people I cite, although he did not realize that there is a profound diference in taking the 4-velocity rather than the 4-momentum in the condition.

Comment: Hi @mike stone and thanks for the reply. So, I have been looking at the paper you discuss (1406.0354), appendix D, in which you derive an expression for what you call "Pauli-Lubansky Spin Tensor". You further provide a physical interpretation of the above-mentioned Spin tensor as an "intrinsic angular momentum about the lab-frame centroid"... I am not sure I 100% understand what is going on in that appendix, some concepts are new for me and therefore hard to grasp (i.e. the mass centroid: why is it defined like that and what is the difference from the centre of mass?).

Comment: However, I couldn't help but notice that your final expression (D13) for the Pauli-Lubansky spin tensor has a similar Dirac structure with the paper numbered as (1) in my reference list. Could it be that those expressions, (D13) and Eq. (4.5) from the first paper I cite, are somewhat related? Could it be that Eq. (4.5) is a QED analogue of (D13)? Also, maybe I missread something, but does Eq. (D13) from your paper apply to the case of massless fermions, or also to the case of massive ones, as well? If not, then how would your (D13) equation apply to the case of massless QED?